# Realloc and strcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

My code gives me segfault error: which I don't understand,the debugger says error comes from printing the value from stored_

```
char *stored_ = NULL;
char testMessage[15];

//strcpy(stored_, testMessage);

for (int a = 0;a < 10; a++)
{
    sprintf(testMessage,"Message::%i\n",a);
    printf("string is:%s;length is %i\n",testMessage,strlen(testMessage));

    stored_ = (char*) realloc (stored_, sizeof(char) * (strlen(testMessage) * (a+1) ));

    strcpy(&stored_[a], testMessage);
} 

for (int b = 0;b < 10; b++)
{
    printf("inside:|%s|\n",stored_[b]);
}
```

Comment: What line is the segfault occurring on?

Comment: You need to add an extra space for the null terminating character ('\0') at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fist up, `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1, you don't need to multiply by it.

Secondly, when you're allocating room for a string, you have to use:

```
malloc (strlen (string) + 1);
```

In other words, you need room for the null byte at the end.

Thirdly, you appear to be confused between character pointers and character *pointer* pointers. `stored_` is a single block of characters and `stored_[1]` is only one byte beyond `stored_[0]`, meaning you won't have enough room to store the string.

```
stored_[n], n=:   0   1   2   3
                +---+---+---+---+
                |   |   |   |   |...
                +---+---+---+---+
                each of these cells is a single byte.
```

You'll either have to manage the single block of characters yourself, leaving enough room for each element (by using sparse indexes), or have a block of character pointers with indexes 0, 1, 2 and so on, but you'll then have to manage the string allocations separately.

The following code shows how to do this latter one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    // An array of char pointers (C strings).

    char **stored_ = NULL;
    char testMessage[15];
    int i;

    // Populate them.

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sprintf (testMessage,"Message::%i",i);
        printf ("string is:%s;length is %i\n",testMessage,strlen(testMessage));

        // Reallocate array of char *, allocate room for string, then store it.

        stored_ =  realloc (stored_,sizeof (char*) * (i + 1));
        stored_[i] = malloc (strlen (testMessage) + 1);
        strcpy (stored_[i], testMessage);
    }
```

That's the meat of it, the allocation of the array of character pointers *separate* from the actual arrays of characters forming the C strings.

Then the code below prints them and cleans up.

```
    // Print them.

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("inside:|%s|\n",stored_[i]);
    }

    // Free all memory and return.

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free (stored_[i]);
    }
    free (stored_);

    return 0;
}
```

The output being, as expected:

```
string is:Message::0;length is 10
string is:Message::1;length is 10
string is:Message::2;length is 10
string is:Message::3;length is 10
string is:Message::4;length is 10
string is:Message::5;length is 10
string is:Message::6;length is 10
string is:Message::7;length is 10
string is:Message::8;length is 10
string is:Message::9;length is 10
inside:|Message::0|
inside:|Message::1|
inside:|Message::2|
inside:|Message::3|
inside:|Message::4|
inside:|Message::5|
inside:|Message::6|
inside:|Message::7|
inside:|Message::8|
inside:|Message::9|
```

With this method, each cell is a pointer to an array of characters, separately allocated (which holds the C string):

```
stored_[n], n=:   0   1   2   3
                +---+---+---+---+
                |   |   |   |   |...
                +---+---+---+---+
                  |   |   |   |     +----------------------+
                  |   |   |   +---> | character array here |
                  |   |   |         +----------------------+
                  |   |   |         +----------------------+
                  |   |   +-------> | character array here |
                  |   |             +----------------------+
                  |   |             +----------------------+
                  |   +-----------> | character array here |
                  |                 +----------------------+
                  |                 +----------------------+
                  +---------------> | character array here |
                                    +----------------------+
```

Comment: And fourthly, it's %d, not %i :)

Comment: Actually, `d` and `i` are equally valid under C99 at least.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be calculating the string length of `stored_` correctly.

Every loop you assign `testMessage` to `&stored_[loopindex]`. I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour, but it's what you're doing, so I'd expect your 10th iteration to give the string `"MMMMMMMMMessage::9\n"`.

Anyway, `testMessage` is always the same number of characters, so the storage space required by `stored_` could be calculated as:

```
strlen(testMessage) // length of str to place at &stored_[a]
+ a                 // the loop index, where you're inserting testMessage
+ 1                 // important! extra char to hold the null terminator
```

Don't ever forget the +1, every string in C must have space for the [null terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).